# xquery : how to check for existance of list of elements?

Tags: xquery

Is there any way to check for existence of list of elements in xml document? The element names are stored in sequence, If the xml document contains any of the elements (names stored in sequence) then return YES otherwise return NO. I tried below example and it did not work.Any suggestion please?

```
<book category="COOKING">
   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
   <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
 </book>
```

let $doc:=doc("book.xml")/book 
    let $fields := ('title','author')

```
return 
    if(doc/*:$fields)   
    then 
    "YES"
    else "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return 
    if($fields[not(.=$doc/*/name())]
    then 
    "No"
    else "YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
if(/*/*/name() = ('title', 'author'))
  then 'YES'
  else 'NO'
```

**Or, alternatively**:

```
('YES'[$doc/*/*/name() = $fields], 'NO')[1]
```